# RequestMapping inheritence between class level and method level

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

Given the `@Controller` below, even if i send a Get Request to the webApp, the controller run the homePage method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class MyController {

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String homePage() {
            return "Hello, It is my first application";
        }
    }
```

How could that happen? Normally, i restrict that from the class level.

Comment: They are agregated (not limited). So when doing a `value` it is added `method` is also added so now bot GET and POST are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method with [@GetMapping("/hello")](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) picked up as most specific and enables GET requests with `/hello` path

> This annotation can be used both at the class and at the method level. In most cases, at the method level applications will prefer to use one of the HTTP method specific variants @GetMapping

Comment: I tried to use @GetMapping() on the class level, but the compiler complains.

Comment: @zakzak GetMapping is allowed only on methods https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html